# Can Twitter's embedded tweets be rendered dynamically?

Tags: javascript, twitter

Twitter's new-ish 'embedded tweets' feature is nice, but as far as I can tell the Twitter API's widgets.js can only render the embedded tweets at page load.

The doc page for embedded tweets is here: [Embedded Tweets | Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets)

It describes an oembed endpoint for "dynamically rendering" a tweet, but this only returns the bare HTML code that must still be transformed by widgets.js.

If I dynamically load some content via Ajax and insert it into the DOM, and that content includes the code for an embedded tweet, is there a way to get widgets.js to render that embedded tweet dynamically? A function or method call maybe?

Answer (score 8):

It's possible to do by calling `twttr.widgets.load()`. Pass in an HTMLElement as the first argument to limit the search for uninitialized widgets to that element. For example:

```js
twttr.widgets.load(document.getElementById("container"))
```

Source: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/scripting-loading-and-initialization

Comment: Thanks, that almost does it. The problem is that twttr.widgets.load() doesn't support a context; it always goes through the whole page. That's way too much overhead if you're just updating one small section. However, they're apparently planning to add a context option soon, according to this discussion: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/890

Comment: I just started using this function. They have added a context to the call.

Answer (score 4):

The link(s) to the docs referenced above lead to blank pages, so here it is again: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/overview.html

Scroll all the way down to the ***Render a Tweet with JavaScript*** section.

Pass your tweet to `twttr.widgets.load` like so:

```
twttr.widgets.load(${tweet.html})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this in **jQuery** by doing the following:

```
$.getScript ( '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', callBack );
```

The **callback** function fires when the script has finished loading.